# Convert SVG to JPEG with Imagemagick, missing external raster graphics

Tags: image, svg, imagemagick

I would like to convert a simple svg graphic to a jpeg one. Here is the svg source code:

```
<svg style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  width="300" version="1.1" height="200">
     <image x="10" y="10" width="276" height="110" 
     xlink:href="http://images.google.com/intl/de_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif"
     stroke-width="1"></image>
  <rect x="0" y="150" height="10" width="300" style="fill: #000000"/>
</svg>
```

If i do the conversion on my windows XP mashine with ImageMagick 6.7.8 all is working fine.

```
convert test.svg test.jpg
```

[image: Conversion with windows]

If i do the same conversion on my linux server (Debian 6.0 ImageMagick 6.6.0) get only the black line.

[image: Conversion on linux server]

I tried to upgrade to the latest Imagemagick version on my linux mashine but i get no newer version from the repository.

But i'm not sure if the use of external images is a feature from the newer version, or if it is a configuration issue.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: what does convert --version say on your two machines?

Comment: I had the version `Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2012-08-17 Q16` installed. And you confirmed in your answer that this version is not working as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check your version with

convert --version

the following version happily does the intended conversion:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-0 2012-05-27 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features:  OpenCL
```

It is available in the current macports port.

This version:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2012-04-30 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS did not work ...

Answer (score 5):

@Wolfgang

I have almost the same verison of imagemagick as yours. (The release is not the same, but I don't think that will cause problem)

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

And my system is :

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu-Secure-Remix 12.04.1 LTS 31.08.2012
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

I have tested in my system, it works well the command.

Or it exist another command :

```
rsvg-convert
```

It could be installed by type (in Ubuntu) :

```
apt-get install librsvg2-bin
```

And to convert a SVG to PNG, the command is :

```
rsvg-convert your_file.svg > your_file.png
```

Comment: rsvg-convert version 2.40.10 seems not to fetch external images

Answer (score 1):

If there is no newer version in the Debian repository, your options are:

1. Compile it yourself from the [**ImageMagick source code**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php). Instructions are [**here**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#unix).
2. Install a [**pre-compiled non-Debian binary**](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/) package (.tar.gz).
3. Use Google and search for the official Debian Squeeze (a.k.a. 6.0) 'backport' repository. If you are lucky, there may be a newer ImageMagick available.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try [Apache Batik SVG Rasterizer](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html)

```
java -jar batik-rasterizer.jar samples/batikFX.svg
```

It does fetch external images.