# Imagick SVG cannot load the image

Tags: php, image, svg, rendering, imagick

I am getting the trouble about converting the SVG to image by PHP Imagick library.
Here is my code:

```
$svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="754" version="1.1" height="565">
    <defs></defs>
    <image transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0" y="0" width="754" height="565" xlink:href="http://1439.demo.tekk3.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/capapix_Harley_Davidson_FLSTCI_-_Heritage_Classic.jpg"></image>
</svg>';

$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImageBlob($svg);
$im->setImageFormat("jpeg");
$im->writeimage($attached_file);
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

And the result is an image with only white background. There are no any other images as SVG showing.

If i put the text tag into the SVG string, only the text rendered in the white background. The image is still missing.

I have installed the php5-imagick, libxml2, librsvg2-bin

Are there any other extensions that i need to install to get the correct result?
Or is there any problem in my code?

Comment: How big is the generated file?

Comment: here is the result that i got: http://1439.demo.tekk3.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Harley_Davidson_FLSTCI_-_Heritage_Classic.jpg

Comment: Strange:  For being blank, it sure has a lot of content, but I ran it though GIMP and tried enhancing contrast, finding edges, looking at a histogram:  it is a big blank.  Maybe change the output type to SVG so you can view the internal content?

Comment: How can i change it? You mean change output the image format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert SVG to JPEG with Imagemagick, missing external raster graphics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879867/convert-svg-to-jpeg-with-imagemagick-missing-external-raster-graphics)

Comment: I solved the problem. I have to change to use the local path for the image, not the web url.

Comment: From [link](http://1439.demo.tekk3.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/capapix_Harley_Davidson_FLSTCI_-_Heritage_Classic.jpg) to /home/svincoll4/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/capapix_Harley_Davidson_FLSTCI_-_Heritage_Classic.jpg

Answer (score 3):

I found workaround. I use base64 image content instand of image path.

```
$svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="754" version="1.1" height="565">
        <image x="0" y="0" width="754" height="565" xlink:href="'.imageToBase64('icons-weather_01.png').'"></image>
    </svg>';

function imageToBase64($path) {
    $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $data = file_get_contents($path);
    return 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
}
```

It if possible to use local image or web url.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use link to the image if you want Imagick to consider your images when converting.
instead use the base64 encoded data corresponding to those images. this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and ended up here, didn't see the solution in the comment (had to click on 'show more comments') until I'd fixed it myself anyway, so thought it might be worth posting it as an answer (as well as upvoting):

As @Phuc-Pham discovered, the problem is that Imagick wants the whole server path, not a path relative to CWD or HTTP document root in the href attribute.

So using his code above the solution should be something along the lines of:

```
$svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="754" version="1.1" height="565">
    <defs></defs>
    <image transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0" y="0" width="754" height="565" xlink:href="/path/to/htdocs/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/capapix_Harley_Davidson_FLSTCI_-_Heritage_Classic.jpg"></image>
</svg>';
```

Hope that's useful.