# imagick php svg to jpg conversion missing image elements

Tags: php, svg, imagick

would really appreciate your help!

i'm using the following PHP code to convert SVG file to jpg.
the code works, but the generated image is missing the image elements from the svg.

the code i'm using:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImageBlob($svg);
$im->setImageFormat("jpeg");
$im->writeImage($jpg_path);
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

the svg i'm using to test is:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="500" 
height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 4.2.0</desc>
<defs>
</defs>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 250 250)" id="697fd54a-8a47-479a-95ac-     
3929f83f9c08"  >
<rect style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none;     
stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; 
stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(255,255,255); fill-rule: nonzero; 
opacity: 1;" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"  x="-250" y="-250" 
rx="0" ry="0" width="500" height="500" />
</g>
<g transform="matrix(Infinity NaN NaN Infinity 0 0)" id="cc4d184b- 
b672-4d1a-b6fd-dc7d2a567e07"  >
</g>
<g transform="matrix(3.79 0 0 3.79 217.48 217.48)" id="75e8436a-136b- 
4014-9427-ac7b9b4560b2"  >
<circle style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: 
none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: 
miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(101,101,101); fill-rule: 
nonzero; opacity: 1;" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"  cx="0" 
cy="0" r="35" />
</g>
<g transform="matrix(0.14 0 0 0.14 217.62 226.7)" id="396bdad1-f05e- 
423e-9935-e14b2b029a4a"  >
<image style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; 
stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; 
stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 
1;" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"  xlink:href="http://...." 
x="-540" y="-810" width="1080" height="1620"></image>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 265.57 421.75)" style="" id="414d0483- 
439e-4020-8816-b41e4d9fb2db"  >
    <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="Raleway" font-size="105" 
font-style="normal" font-weight="900" style="stroke: none; stroke- 
width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke- 
dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: 
rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" > 
<tspan x="-137.76" y="32.98" >Louis</tspan></text>
</g>
</svg>
```

the result image contain the text, rect and circle elements.
but not the image element.

Comment: Check your root folder for newly generated image.

Comment: what do you mean?
the jpg image is being created, but is missing the image elements from the SVG file

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Imagick SVG cannot load the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796649/imagick-svg-cannot-load-the-image) especially the 2nd answer

Comment: @Tschallacka unfortunately no :( this problem occurs on both when the image element is a full valid link or base64